# What is the purpose of mdf file?

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an MDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175882/what-is-an-mdf-file)

What is the purpose of the mdf file if the database is SQLEXPRESS in following connection string :

```
connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
```

Just something that is not clear after a few tutorials. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MDF file is your Data File - where the database structure and all the data are stored.