# Installed VS2012 and SSME 2012 with LocalDB. What's the server name?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I just installed VS2012, SSME 2012 with LocalDB, now I want to connect to server

[image]

What's ther server name?, I tried Rafael-PC\sqlexpress, .\sqlexpress, localdb, etc..

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(localdb)\v11.0**

More info at this SO thread:  [SQL Server (localdb)\v11.0 explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780941/sql-server-localdb-v11-0-explained)