# Cannot find my Entity Framework database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am a little confused on the code first entity framework database.

I created a new DbContext and class that I will be storing in that context, like this:

```
namespace MyProject.Subproject.Something
{
    public class MyItem
    {
        public string One { get; set; }
        public string Two { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public string Three { get; set; }
        public string Four { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyAppData : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I know that it's working since I can do this without failure:

```
var db = new MyAppData();
MyItem i = new MyItem();
// ... fill in item
db.MyItems.Add(i);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Additionally, if I restart the application I find `db.MyItems.Count()` to reflect that items are in fact persistently stored somewhere.

I'm assuming this is stored in `localdb` since I set up no SQL Server database.  All I want to be able to do is see the table in `localdb` somewhere, however I can't seem to find it.

If I go to `Data Sources -> Add New Data Source -> Database -> Data Set -> New Connection -> Microsoft SQL Server` and then put in `(localdb)v11.0` for the Server Name and dropdown the list of databases, I do not see MyAppData or MyItems listed.

**Edit**:  What I see in my App.config is `<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">`

---

**Edit 2**:  Full App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxx" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You must have a connection string in your config. Check there, it will show the path.

Comment: If it's not in localdb, try SQL Express. Use `[My-PC-NAME]\SQLEXPRESS` as connection string. For me, it's JEROEN-DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS. Do note that the name might be "DefaultConnection" or something similar.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose this is what I see: `<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">`

Comment: Can you paste the complete connection node from your config in the post

Comment: @PraveenPaulose added the full App.config

Comment: Try setting your connection in the Explorer to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB

Comment: Wow, that worked!  I have never seen that connection string anywhere.  Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You might want to refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780941/sql-server-localdb-v11-0-explained

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set your database server as `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`. This is a change made to EF 6.1.1 onwards. The MSSQLLocalDB is mentioned in your parameter. More details on the change can be found here https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2246

**MSSQLLocalDB** is the default instance name on SQL Server 2014 whereas **v11.0** is the default Instance name on SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2):

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
  var connectionString = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
  Console.WriteLine(connectionString); 
}
```

The above code uses the Microsoft example; for BloggingContext substitute your `DbContext` class.  It will give you the connection string that the entity framework is using, which includes the instance name.

Comment: This helped me troubleshoot an evasive issue. simple yet effective .Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yep - based on the parameter in your defaultConnectionFactory it looks like you're using the default SQL 2014 instance, not the 2012 instance.

The (localdb)\ProjectsV12 instance is created by SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)

(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB is the SQL Server 2014 LocalDB default instance name

And (localdb)\v11.0 is the SQL Server 2012 LocalDB default instance name