# I developed an application in C#, is it possible to run this application on another PC which has no SQL Server and Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I developed a desktop application in C# and save data into SQL Server. Is it possible to run this application on another PC which has no SQL Server and Visual Studio if it is possible then how to do that

Comment: Well, if you store data into SQL Server - you have to be able to *connect* to a SQL Server somewhere on the local network where this PC runs.... and also, since it's a .NET application, you must have the correct .NET framework installed on that PC as well

Comment: Yes, but you need SQL Server somewhere if you are using it. Visual Studio is just an IDE.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780941/sql-server-localdb-v11-0-explained

Comment: @marc_s so where can i save this data so that every PC can use this application without any tool...?

Comment: In that case, you need to store it into a file, e.g. a text file, binary file, XML file - or a file-based database (like SQLite or SQL Server Compact)

Comment: if i have 20000 entries so in file handling is this so slow as compared to database ?

Comment: Well, yes, there is a **good reason** why databases were "invented" - to make this easier. So if your application **needs** a database - make sure your users have a database available ....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You will need to set the connection string in your application with the connection information needed to connect to a remote database. You can always check out http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

to see some examples of SQL connection strings.