# How to convert .sql file into .mdf file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mdf

I have a `.sql` file. How can I convert this `.sql` file to a `.mdf` SQL Server database file?

I know that `.sql` file is nothing but a script file if I open the `.sql` file in notepad it will show me the db code I can simply copy those code and paste into SQL Server Management Studio.

Is there any other way to convert `.sql` to `.mdf` file?

Comment: Does youe SQL file have `CREATE DATABASE` in it? What happens when you run it?

Comment: Yes in the .sql file their is a CREATE DATABASE query in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your SQL file contains the script to create a database, your question wouldn't make any sense.  If it does contain such script you need an environment to execute it.  There are many tools that will allow you to do that.  For example, many `IDE` tools that integrate with SQL Server have such capability.

So to answer your question: it is **impossible** to *convert* `SQL` file to [`MDF`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175882/what-is-an-mdf-file). You, however, can sometimes **use** an `SQL` file to **build** `MDF`.

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem. :)