# Error when trying to open() sql server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wcf, sqlconnection

I am new to net developing and have managed to work my way through a lot of questions I have had just by looking through the forums.

It appears that the issue that I am having is something that a number of others have had I have found that they are all different and just haven't for the life of me been able to work through it.

I am trying to insert player registration details into database but when I try to invoke the wcf server it am met with the exception type on my conn.Open():

An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code.

In addition I am using the build it sql server and the connection string used is one from properties on the database. 
I am not too sure how to proceed.

```
public string playerRegistration(playerDetails playerInfo)
{            
    string Message;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\\Users\\Daniel\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\Prac4\\WebApplication1\\App_Data\\ADODatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Player(pid, pfname, plname, pphone, paddress, pdob) VALUES (@pid, @pfname, @plname, @pphone, @paddress, @pdob)", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", playerInfo.Pid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pfname", playerInfo.Pfname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plname", playerInfo.Plname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pphone", playerInfo.Pphone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paddress", playerInfo.Paddress);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdob", playerInfo.Pdob);

            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result == 1)
            {
                Message = " Details inserted successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                Message = " Details not inserted successfully";
            }
            conn.Close();
            return Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to open the database using SQL Management Studio?

Comment: wrap this line around a `int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); try{}catch{SqlException e}` report back to use what the e.Message is also use this link it will give you many examples of how to format a [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/) in C#

Comment: As an aside, you don't need `conn.Close()` with `using`.
`

Comment: I have created the database on VS. I am not too sure will that assist in telling me whether it is the connection string or the database?

Comment: You would have received a faster answer if you had posted the entire exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to use `@".."` (a [verbatim string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311988/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-string-and-a-verbatim-string)) with connection strings to avoid simple escaping mistakes.

The code shown with `"..\v.."` contains a [vertical tab escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters) which produces an invalid connection string. There is no compiler error because the string literal is *syntactically valid* although the resulting string is incorrect.

Recommended fix with a verbatim string literal and elimination of double slashes:

```
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\Users\Daniel.."
```

Alternative fix (note the `\\v`):

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\\Users\\Daniel.."
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your connection string

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\\Users\\Daniel\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\Prac4\\WebApplication1\\App_Data\\ADODatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

Search the internet to find the required format for SQL Server.  You do not need an MDF file name, here's a helpful link:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Why do you think that OP uses Access, he's clearly using SQL-Server.

Comment: The name of his MDF file in the connection string, in the AttachDbFilename section.  Hence my thoughts that the entire connection string is incorrect

Comment: But a mdf-file is a sql-server file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175882/what-is-an-mdf-file

Comment: Oh ok. I had a look through there but I am using the sql server on visual studio I tried "Server =(LocalDB)\v11.0;Database = ADODatabase;Trusted_Connection=True" but received the same error. Do you think it would be the database causing the issues?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ooops thanks...got confused with Access. Edited answer.

Comment: @DanielAguirre-Davies The connection string is quite specific, and this is indeed the problem.

Comment: I have found on the link is the detail that I have gone into the problem or perhaps the detail of the filename Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;
AttachDbFileName=C:\MyFolder\MyData.mdf;

Comment: Hi @DanielAguirre-Davies, user user2864740 has posted a more accurate answer.  You need an extra \ character before the v in v11.10