# DbSets appear empty in MVC5 EF Code First Project but DB appears populated in Server Explorer

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

There's a very strange thing happening when I debug in Visual Studio.

I have a local database defined thus in Web.config...

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\cms_test_data;Initial Catalog=cms_test_data;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I debug the project the DbSet objects are empty. For example Pages (see below) returns a Count of 0 at a breakpoint in a Page controller action.

But when I examine the tables in Server Explorer they are populated with the test data.

Here is how my DB Context is defined...

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    ...

public ApplicationDbContext()
                : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

Even more strangely, when I use an external database this all works.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you are examining the tables in |DataDirectory|\cms_test_data?

Comment: @artm In Solution Explorer I'm double-clicking the cms_test_data.mdf file in the App_Data folder.

Comment: ... but I've noticed there is also a file called "cms_test_data" (with no extension) in this folder. Any idea what this contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears my connectionString contained **AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\cms_test_data** instead of **AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\cms_test_data.mdf** and indeed there was a file in the App_Data folder called cms_test_data (no file extension).

It appears the SQL Server doesn't care whether the database file has an extension, let alone a ".mdf" extension. See [What is an MDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175882/what-is-an-mdf-file).

So when **cmd_test_data** was put into the connection string instead of **cmd_test_data.mdf**, a blank database with this name was created, alongside the existing .mdf file.