# Is the .mdf file in my project an embedded DB?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am not so into **.NET** technologies (I came from Java) and I have a question.

I followed a tutorial that uses **Entity Framework** to access data in a database. It works fine.

My question is: at the moment I have not yet installed **SQL Server** or other RDBMS on my machine. I can access to this database directly from Visual Studio (in my project structure I go to the `App_Data` that contains a `.mdf` file.

So what is this file? Is it something like a "file system based" DB?

Comment: The mdf file contains the database, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175882/what-is-an-mdf-file.

Comment: That MDF file is a SQL Server database file, which connected to your project using SQL Server Express by using `AttachDBFileName` parameter. It automatically created when MVC project with user authentication enabled was chosen.

Comment: If you're using a `.mdf`, you **DO HAVE** SQL Server installed - either a "full" version, or the free SQL Server **Express**, or the developer-targeted "LocalDB" version. A `.mdf` file is **not** an "embedded" database - you **must have** SQL Server installed in some way, shape or form to use it