# How do I extract a specific string from the first line of a .log file and ignore all the special characters?

Tags: string, batch-file, logging, special-characters

I have a log file where the first line is very long and full of strange (ASCII?) characters. There is a timestamp in there that I need to extract so I can rename the file. That line looks like this:

```
MDF             CANwin I    ,                                  HD¤ ¶ (¶      21:12:202214:14:44                                                                                                                                  Q    p       e™    Ñ     48-375Šš    Q    `       øš    Ñ    -001   œ    Q    @    yœ    Ñ    Cpz  «    ð¨±Œ   ÿÿÿÿÿÿ¸ž    ðóÿ”  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿTóž    àôÿˆ  ...
```

I need to extract the timestamp `21:12:202214:14:44`.

This will only return line1 as "MDF":

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set name=%~n1
set /p line1=< %name%.log
echo %line1%
```

I realize there are limits to /p but this is the only way I've gotten any output.

Edit:
These files are coming from a memorator on a vehicle in Vector Log (.log) format. They are "readable" in Notepad.

Comment: With the `MDF` magic number, it's more likely that instead of being a regular log file, this is actually a SQL Server database. You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175882/what-is-an-mdf-file or https://serverfault.com/questions/31105/opening-mdf-files about accessing them more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /p "line="<q75837443.txt
FOR %%e IN (%line%) DO (
 SET "datestring=%%e"
 IF "!datestring:~2,1!!datestring:~5,1!!datestring:~12,1!!datestring:~15,1!"=="::::" GOTO found
 SET "datestring="
)
:found
SET datestring
GOTO :EOF
```

Where `q75837443.txt` is your log file.

Read the line, then simply assign each space-separated element to `%%e` and `datestring` in turn. If the 2nd,5th,12th,15th character in `datestring` (counting from the start=`0`th character) are all colons, go to `found` with the string.